# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, port

My apache is running properly but mysql server is showing this error

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
[mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
[mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
[mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
[mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
[mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this
[mysql] entire log window on the forums
```

I tried deleting ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ib_logfile101 files, but it didn't workout.  Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

We could use this information to help you out.

Possibilties: 
incorect config - try to restore some known good config
 blocked port - quite often its skype(especially older versions of skype), try changing MySQL port

Comment: This should be a comment, not an actual answer!

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issues today.

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
7:56:51 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:56:51 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:56:52 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:56:52 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:56:52 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
7:56:52 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

#### Solution:

1. Stop the Apache Service, then
2. Copy all files from xampp\mysql\backup, and paste all files inside xampp\mysql\data.
3. Start Apache

...and MySQL is working perfectly.

Comment: For some weird reason this worked for me too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

```
22:41:18  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 
22:41:18  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  
22:41:18  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 
22:41:18  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 
22:41:18  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 
22:41:18  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this 
22:41:18  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

But it didn't work even after copying all files from xampp\mysql\backup, and pasting them inside xampp\mysql\data Or when I deleted ibdata1 file.

So, I went through this link.
[Free the port number](https://www.w3raja.com/how-to-free-up-port-number-3306-in-wamp-xampp-server/#:%7E:text=%20%20%201%20Step%201%3A%20Run%20your,5%3A%20Now%20restart%20your%20wamp%20server.%20More%20)

**Stop your Apache module in xampp control panel.**

**Open command prompt and Run as Administrator**

Type “netstat -ano” in the cmd prompt. This will show all the port connections in your network.

```
netstat -ano
```

Now find your port number and use it in the find string. In my case, it is 3306.
Type “netstat -ano | findstr 3306” in cmd prompt and hit enter.

```
netstat -ano | findstr 3306
```

Find the listening id of 3306. In my case, 5224 is my listening id.
Kill that process id with “taskkill /PID 6204 /F“.

```
taskkill /PID 5224 /F
```

[image]

**SUCCESS: The process with PID 5224 has been terminated.** will be the output.
Restart the xampp Server.

And it worked!